# Run animation until a button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiviewanimation

I am trying to make an app in which animation should run until a button is pressed. I tried to use infinite loop but with that loop my app is not running at all. It is consuming all the memory. I also tried to call the same function again on completion but that process is also consuming 100% of CPU.

Can you please guide me what should i do here?

Scenario is like in the background of the view, animation should run continuously until a button is pressed. Another view will open when the button will be pressed and again another animation will run continuously until some other button is pressed.
Following is my code:

```
func unlimitedLoop()
    {            
        rotating = true            
        self.ProcurementSupport.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 100)
        self.ProcurementSupport.hidden = false            
        UIView.animateWithDuration(3, delay: 2, usingSpringWithDamping: 2, initialSpringVelocity: 2, options: nil, animations: {
            //   self.EquipmentSupport.hidden = true

            var x:NSTimeInterval = 2                    
                springWithDelay(2, x, {
                    self.ProcurementSupport.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,0)
                    self.EquipmentSupport.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(1000,0)
                    x=x+2
                })                    
                springWithDelay(2, x, {
                    self.EquipmentSupport.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,100)
                    x=x+2
                })                    
                springWithDelay(2, x, {
                    self.ProcurementSupport.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(1000,0)
                    self.EquipmentSupport.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,0)
                    x=x+2
                })
                springWithDelay(2, x, {
                    self.ProcurementSupport.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 100)
                    x=x+2
                })
            }, completion: {finished in self.unlimitedLoopAgain()})
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing custom animations by creating an infinite loop you need to run this function on a separate thread. Beside the loop itself it best to stop the thread for a small amount of time every frame, for instance call sleep for 1.0/60.0 to get about 60FPS. Another problem that comes up in this approach is that when a new thread changes a parameter on the view system it will most likely call back on the main thread for the view to be refreshed "set needs display". In no case should you create such a function and in it call a built in animation as you did, you need to do the animation yourself.

A better approach is usually using some kind of timer or a display link in your case. This item will trigger every time the display should redraw so it is perfect for your animation. These calls are most usually already on the main thread so you do not need anything else. Again calling a built in animation should be avoided then.

Yet another way would be to use kind of a recursion. Every time you update the animation you call the same update method after some delay time (1.0/60.0) for instance...

Anyway your infinite loop just keeps executing and takes all the processor power but no other method is executed because of it so you can see no result at all. You need a way to let the system perform other methods in between the frames (the update calls) so either stop executing for some period of time after every update or put it on a separate thread. Both of these ways will let the main thread to do other stuff as well.